# How to merge 2 one page PDF files

Tags: macos, pdf, preview

On `Lion` (from memory, and I can't check anymore) this method:

- open a one page PDF `doc2` (with `Preview`),
- open a one page PDF `doc1` (with `Preview`),
- drag thumbnail from `doc1` onto `doc2`,
- save as (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>) onto `doc3`

was an easy way to make:

```
doc3 = doc1 + doc2
```

or in Unix talk:

```
cat doc1 doc2 >doc3
```

Apparently (fixes appreciated) since `Mountain Lion` this simple receipe doesn't work anymore.

---

What is the easy way to achieve such a basic operation for PDF files:

- given 2 PDF documents `doc1` and `doc2`,
- I want to get `doc3 = doc1 + doc2`,
- with as simple an application as `Preview`,
- within a few seconds of click, click, click….

I need this basic function for users running `Mountain Lion`, `Mavericks`, `Yosemite`.

Comment: This still works on Yosemite...

Comment: and in Mavericks...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the two PDFs with Preview

Drag the thumbnails of the second PDF to the end of the first PDF but **above the grey line** (marked with the red arrow):

[image: pdf1]

[image: pdf2]

and finally export the resulting PDF to a third PDF.

If your first PDF contains just one page this doesn't work.

Workaround 1: Open your second PDF, then open the first PDF, drag the single page to the beginning of the second PDF and export the resulting PDF to a third PDF.

Workaround 2: Insert an empty second page at the end of the first page.

[image: blank]

[image: blank2]

and drag the second PDF to the regular end of your first PDF

[image: blank3]

delete the empty page at the end and export the remaining pages to a new third PDF.

Comment: I've also found that doing a Print to PDF then Save does work with single page PDF merging after you've dragged them into the new PDF